# DataBufferInt cannot be resolved to a type

Tags: java, eclipse

I'm using eclipse java and i'm a newbie programmer, lately I've been using different online resources to  to try to make my own simple game. However I have run into the issue where `DataBufferInt cannot be resolved to a type`.

```
public Main()  {
    screen = new Screen(WIDTH, HEIGHT);
    img = new BufferedImage(WIDTH, HEIGHT, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
    pixels = ((DataBufferInt) img.getRaster().getDataBuffer()).getData();
}
```

`((DataBufferInt) img.getRaster().getDataBuffer())` is where the error is happening.

I have tried restarting, and deleting and re-adding the JRE library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you importing `java.awt.image.DataBufferInt`?

Check whether you have

```
import java.awt.image.DataBufferInt;
```

or

```
import java.awt.image.*;
```

at the top of your Main.java file (above `public Main() {`)

Comment: I'm pretty sure you meant `import java.awt.image.*;` in your second code example.